# asp.net Generic repository find by property

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, repository-pattern

I am using Generic Repositories with ASP.NET. Now I am trying to find an object by the user Id which requires to access a property of the class, but ofcourse in the linq expression the property is not know, because it does not know the type yet. Is there any way around this?

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetByUser(string userId)
    {
        if (typeof(T).GetProperty("Employee") != null)
        {
            return Db.Set<T>().Where(x => x.Employee.Id == userId);
        }
        return new List<T>();
    }
```

the "x.Employee.Id" gets the error that there is no definition of Employee. That is to be expected. Do I need to do this in an entire different way or does somebody knows how to fix this?

I hope anybody can help!

Comment: You could use `Interfaces` here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interfaces so that you know `T` will have certain properties. Or use a base type and then use constraints on the generic parameter.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetByUser(string userId) where T : IEmployee
{
   return Db.Set<T>().Where(x => x.Employee.Id == userId);
}
```

And where `IEmployee` looks like this

```
public interface IEmployee 
{
    Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously this is a bit crude, but depending on your entities this could be an approach. You could always map out everything and then build up your interfaces for the shared properties etc.

However to be honest I think your best approach is to have a more functional set of generic repositories. For example a base repo, and then an `EmployeeRepostiory` that knows that `T` will be an Employee.

**[MSDN Article on Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)**

Comment: I agree that that would be easier, but it feels very dirty to make separate repositories for every entity if they have the same functionality and only inherit the base.

Comment: @RonaldRozema I know the benefits of a Generic Repository but you are going to have use something to constrain the types. A nice approach I always use is for my `IRepository` I always have `T` constrained to `IBase` which is just an Id. And that already covers a lot of your standard methods for retrieval etc

You use the base for everything, and then just use the EmployeeRepository methods for things not covered by the base. For example it's hardly `generic` if you are using a custom type in there without constraints

Comment: Allright that gives me enough to finish this. Thanks for the input, much appreciated!